# T-test on two columns in R

Tags: r, t-test

I am trying to do a t-test to see if the values in two columns on two dfs are statistically different.

I am trying to run a code that compares the "Duration" column in two dfs -- "Tokens" and "Tokens.Single". Both dfs have the same number of values in their respective duration columns.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
# T-test for duration.
t.test(Tokens$Duration ~ Tokens.Single$Duration, paired=FALSE, var.equal=TRUE)
```

And this is the error message I received:

```
Error in t.test.formula(Tokens$Duration ~ Tokens.Single$Duration, paired = FALSE,  : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Use `Tokens$Duration,Tokens.Single$Duration` rather than `Tokens$Duration ~ Tokens.Single$Duration`

Answer (score 3):

Without a peak at your data, it's hard to say, but the syntax you are using in `t.test` is usually for response by factor variable.

Based on your description of your data you would be better to use the following syntax:

```
y <- rnorm(50)
x <- rnorm(50)

t.test(x,y)
```

Which will result in a comparison of means between x and y numeric vector, or in your case:

```
t.test(Tokens$Duration , Tokens.Single$Duration, paired=FALSE, var.equal=TRUE)
```

Just for completeness, if you had a factor variable indicating the run or experiment number, you could use the formula syntax e.g.

```
y <- rnorm(50)
z <- rep(c("A","B"), 25)
t.test(y ~z)
```

Yielding:

```
data:  y by z
t = -2.0418, df = 47.504, p-value = 0.04675
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.07859422 -0.00814587
sample estimates:
mean in group A mean in group B 
      0.1162672       0.6596372
```